# Show text for phones and tablets but not desktops

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I have it working on phones but the desktop text shows on the tablet.

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobile {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```
<h1 class="desktop">Desktop</h1>
<h1 class="mobile">Mobile</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

767px is practically the minimum width of the tablet.

You are probably testing on an Ipad. It is safest to set it to 1024px.

Because usually tablets are from 768 to 1024.

I suggest:

```
#header nav li.mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #header nav li.mobile {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #header nav li.desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry did not work.  It actually broke some things that were working. I am very new to this.  I spent the entire night just getting to where I am now.  This is the page. https://www.mymammothtech.com/test.html

Comment: On a desktop the text says "Desktop" and there are 2 icons below it.  On the phone the text says "Mobile" and there are 3 icons.  When I make your change the text is good but all of the icons show up on both pages. I am going to make your change and let you see what I am talking about.

Comment: In case you are bled by incorrect specificy elements. Try new updated code. A great article for you: [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I ended up using https://app.urlgeni.us/ and with your code everything is working!!!  Thank you!!!